Virtual Machine gets an IP address but without asking for one from the dhcp server
A VM setup with the libvirt terraform kvm provider doesn't get an IP address from my dhcp server. It still gets an address but isn't listed on DNS, which is an issue for the machines to communicate. I've set up a NetworkBridge (host OS is systemd variant of Gentoo) using
A machine built without terraform, but using the same Network bridge performs correctly, i.e. it comes up, registers the hostname with dhcp and gets a dns address
--name altdns --description "alternate DNS server for the home network"  --memory 2048   --vcpus 2   --disk path=/test_zfs/VM_images/ubuntu.qcow2,size=32 --cdrom ./ubuntu-24.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso   --graphics spice   --os-variant ubuntu24.04   --virt-type kvm   --autostart   --network network=VirtBridge

However when I try and use a Debian 12 cloud init image, it gets an ip address, which is valid, but doesn't look like it's ever come into contact with my DHCP server as there's no record of it on there and I can ping the machine via it's host name. I can ping it via ip address (v4). Here's the network config for the cloud image;
version: 2
  ethernets:
    all-en:
      match:
        name: "en*"
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true


and I set up the network bridge using the following xml.
<network>
  <name>VirtBridge</name>
  <forward mode="bridge"/>
  <bridge name="br0"/>
</network>

so it should be just deferring to the router.

What is in the Network config for the Debian VM from the cloud init image? Does the router have a DHCP server? Are there any DHCP servers running anywhere else? Add that information to the question.

That looks like Netplan configuration, and I assume you're using systemd-networkd as its "renderer" (backend), so what does networkctl status enXXXX report about the DHCP lease if any?

Thanks @grawity you put me on the right path. It was odd, I received an ip address, but gave teh dhcp no hostname. Once I did a sudo  systemctl restart systemd-networkd, it got the right ip address and set the hostname and now it's pingable from across my network. Good work!
